# Can you help solve data.entry.init issue?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I'm getting the "thread 1: exc_bad_access (code=2, address=0x16fc0bfefe8) error. I have set up the iOS app to access a Table View Controller after logging in. It should display images. I have been following this tutorial http://shrikar.com/uitableview-and-uitableviewcell-customization-in-swift/ but no luck. This is my data.swift file where the error originates from:

```
import Foundation

class Data {

class Entry: Data {
    let filename : String
    init(fname : String) {
        self.filename = fname
    }

}

let products = [
  Entry(fname: "placeholder1"), // <- Thread 1 error code shows in this line
  Entry(fname: "placeholder2"),
  Entry(fname: "placeholder3")
 ]

}
```

HomeTableViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class HomeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let data = Data()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.products.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
    let entry = data.products[indexPath.row]
    let image = UIImage(named: entry.filename)
    cell.bkImageView.image = image

    return cell
}
```

HomeTableViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var bkImageView: UIImageView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Humbly asking for some assistance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this line:

```
class Entry: Data {
```

Since `Entry` inherits from `Data` when you create an instance of `Data` the program goes into an infinite loop of initializing both the first member of `products` (an `Entry`) and its parent class, `Data`. Instead it should be this, as per the tutorial:

```
class Entry {
```